# Sequence in H2 DB not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to do junit testing in Spring Boot 2.1.4 using H2 embedded db. I am facing a peculiar issue with sequence. So according to spring boot and h2 tutorial, I have a schema.sql script to generate my relevant tables:

```
create sequence seq_test increment by 50;
```

I can see that the create sequence is called from debug logs.

To test if sequence is working, I ran a nextval() on it but got a table seq_test is not created error. This only happens for sequence, when i queried a normal table, I got a proper result.

Test Case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Import({EmbeddedRedis.class, EmbeddedRabbitMQ.class})
@Slf4j
public class ProfileCreationTests {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void profileCreationTest() {
        Query query = em
                .createNativeQuery("SELECT NEXTVAL(seq_test)");
        log.info(query.getSingleResult().toString());
        log.info(em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_test").getSingleResult().toString());
    }


}
```

First line errors out, if i comment it out, second query runs ok.

app config:
    spring:
      profiles: test
      h2:
        console:
          enabled: true
      jpa:
        hibernate:
          use-new-id-generator-mappings: true

Comment: Please properly format the configuration and include the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Query query = em.createNativeQuery("call next value for seq_test");`

h2 offers different [compatibility modes](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility), and syntax for fetching next value differs between them. I think the above syntax is fine when no compatiblility mode is selected.